# How to change if we did mistake in E-Filing income tax in India

Tags: income-tax, india

I have filed income tax for the financial year 2012-2013 using e-filing.

While filing the same, I gave the assessment year as 2012-2013 instead of 2013-2014.

How to rectify this problem ? Can anybody suggest me what to do now ?

Also, now i need to file income tax for the financial year 2013-2014 too. So, in this case, will it affect anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get back an acknowledgement for the e-filing [i.e. ITR V]. Generally the ITR V should have shown the defect in your return. Just file an revised return. Give the details of the Original return Acknowledgement in the relevant column.

The only issue you may encounter if you don't do this is that the tax records will show you have not filed a return. It is advisable to file the amendment ASAP.

This will not affect anything for financial year 2013-14.

It is in the personal tab / section. There is a question whether Original or Revised.

[image]

Comment: Yes Dheer, I got the acknowledgement and they have mentioned that "The Income Tax Department- Centralized Processing Centre (ITD-CPC), Bangalore is not in a position to 
proceed with the e-return filed by you". What is the link to file the revised return ? Where it is located in the indian income tax filing web page ?