# How to pay the due amount after fiing the IT returns in India

Tags: income-tax, india

For the AY 2014-2015, my Tax Payable is INR 8500. Thinking that I would get an option to pay online while submitting, I submitted the IT returns. Obviously, I didn't get an option to pay the due amount online.

Can someone guide me on 
How I should pay the due amount?
How can I update the submitted IT returns?

Answer (score 2):

> How I should pay the due amount?

You can pay by visiting the Income Tax office, collect a blank tax challan and depositing the amount in any Bank by filling your details in the challan. Alternatively most Banks allow you to pay via net banking. You can also pay via Govt website [here](https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp). The Chalan used should be ITNO 280

Note that as you are late there maybe a tax and penalty to pay on the amount due.

> How can I update the submitted IT returns?

The online site will allow you to file an amendment, you need to give the details of the previous returns.

Edit:
Assuming you have filed the Original using the Income Tax India website, you can file an amendment. Refer to the question [How to change if we did mistake in E-Filing income tax in India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/how-to-change-if-we-did-mistake-in-e-filing-income-tax-in-india). If you have used any other service provider, there will be similar provision.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dheer. Since I'm new to IT returns filling, Can you please explain little more for the second question?

Comment: @Ram If you have filed the Original using paper, then you need to file another paper based return. Quote the original reference and on first page mark it as "Revised". If you have filed in online using IncomeTax website, there is an option to select "Amendment"